# ontology representation

Tags: xml, rdf, semantic-web

Can I represent ontology by using XML? Why it is considered better to represent ontology by RDF?

Comment: What do you mean "ontology"? Please explain.

Comment: People at my lab deal with them and talk about them all the time, but yet no-one really seems to know what they are...

Comment: Ontology is the study of reality. What it has to do with XML escapes me.

Comment: I know what ontology is Neil, I guess it wasn't as implied as I thought that I meant "what do you mean by 'ontology' in this context".

Comment: RDF can be represented in XML. XML is just the name of the markup language. RDF in XML is an XML application.

Comment: An ontology (in computing, more than philosophy) is like an object model. For example, you might say a car is a type of vehicle, and red is a type of color, and that a vehicle can have a color. Your ontology would define the classes of things, and the sorts of relationships between them. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29

Comment: in general ontology represent concepts their attribute and relations among concepts 
i need to build an ontology that represent a set of electronic equipments but i want to know if i can represent ontology in xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an ontology can be described using XML, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDF/XML
RDF is pretty old and has mature tools, see also [Web Ontology Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language)

Comment: if i have to list of concepts and i want to find the similarity between these list how can i find how much two list similar?
as an example if i have to list that describe book attribute 
list1(author, brand , isbn, category, amount)
list2(author , price , brand)

Answer (score 4):

If you use RDF, then all of the reasoning engines ([Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/) is my favourite) and triple stores out there can help you. If you want to choose your own format, you won't be able to use any other software that implements the standard.

Answer (score 3):

In many ways, the answer to your question is yes. There are a number of ontology languages which can be serialised in XML. On the web, Web Ontology language is the tool of choice as has been pointed out (which can be serialised in XML). Whether RDF (which can also be serialised in XML) can be considered to be an ontology language is contentious: RDF, unlike OWL, does not give you access to the whole apparatus of first order description logic, but allows you to construct things more akin to controlled vocabularies, taxonomies etc...rather than formal ontologies. Therefore the question of what it is that you mean by "ontology" is actually quite justified: people often use the term ontology when they actually mean "dictionary" or "controlled vocabulary" and others for formal axiomatic systems. Depending on what you want to do, you may even find that first order logic is not enough for you and you may have to go to other (higher order) formalisms.

Answer (score 0):

If by "ontology" you mean OWL then check out the W3C Recommendation [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language XML Serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-xml-serialization/). This XML-based (and **not** RDF-based serialization) is in many cases more suitable for representing OWL ontologies than any RDF-based syntax, e.g. it is easier to write by hand, more straight-forward to manipulate automatically, etc.